# How to generate random library objects using createJS

Tags: javascript, html, easeljs, createjs

I have several library objects ("s0, s1.... sn"), and I want to generate them randomly every time my for cycle loops.

Instead of having:

```
switch(Math.floor(Math.random() * n))
{
     case 0: 
          x = new lib.s0();
          break;
     case 1:
          x = new lib.s1();
          break;
     (...)
}
```

I want it like this;

```
x = new lib.s[Math.floor(Math.random() * n)]();
```

In ActionScript I used to do this, but it doesn't work in createJS

```
x = new (getDefinitionByName("s"+ Math.floor(Math.random() * n)) as Class)
```

So, how can I accomplish this in createJS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access a item of a object with a dynamic key like this:

`x = new lib['s' + Math.floor(Math.random() * n)]();`

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe I didn't try that.